# Android Gradient Application Title Bar

Tags: android, titlebar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I programmatically set the background color gradient on a Custom Title Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115715/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-background-color-gradient-on-a-custom-title-ba)

I want to use gradient color in application title bar. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115715/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-background-color-gradient-on-a-custom-title-ba

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All people are trying to use **Custom title** for this requirement.

I achieved this without using custom title. Just use below code in your activity's onCreate() after setContentView().

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {Color.RED,Color.GREEN});
View title = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
View titleBar = (View) title.getParent();
titleBar.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Enjoy with above code. Below image is screen shot of my app with gradient color as title bar background.

[image: Gradient Color as Background of title bar]

Comment: Very handy code instead going for complex custom title.+1 for that.