# setBackgroundDrawable() deprecated

Tags: android, deprecated, deprecation-warning

So my sdk goes from 15 to 21 and when I call `setBackgroundDrawable()`, Android Studio tells me that it's deprecated.

I thought of going around it using:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_wstat_tstorm));
} else {
    layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_wstat_tstorm));
}
```

But then, I get an error at "setBackground()".

So, how would you deal with it?

Comment: Do you get an error or a warning?

Comment: what value you have of min sdk version in manifest?

Comment: use setbackgroundresource(R.drawable.img_wstat_tstorm); for higher version.setBackgroundDrawable is depricated in higher verion ,this hope help you

Comment: Min sdk is 15. I have "setBackground()" underlined in red but the App runs so I guess it's a warning

Comment: You must be getting *Add @SupressWarning*

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It's an interesting topic. The way you are doing it is correct, apparently. It is actually just a naming decision change. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844271/4015623) points out, `setBackground()` just calls `setBackgroundDrawable()`:

```
public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    //noinspection deprecation
    setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}

@Deprecated
public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) { ... }
```

You can see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11947603/4015623) for more information about all of this.

Comment: You should note that `setBackground()` won't work for pre API16, an alternative could be `setBackgroundResource`

Answer (score 31):

maybe you can try the following:

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_wstat_tstorm);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setBackgroundResource'. it should be setBackgroundDrawableResource

Answer (score 20):

Correct as of 15th August 2018

Use the support libraries

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), drawableRes, null);
ViewCompat.setBackground(layout, drawable);
```

Answer (score 18):

It's funny because that method is deprecated, but if you look at the Android Source Code you'll find this:

```
   /**
     * Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background. If the
     * background has padding, this View's padding is set to the background's
     * padding. However, when a background is removed, this View's padding isn't
     * touched. If setting the padding is desired, please use
     * {@link #setPadding(int, int, int, int)}.
     *
     * @param background The Drawable to use as the background, or null to remove the
     *        background
     */
    public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You are getting an error because getResources().getDrawable() takes an id (int) not a drawable as its argument. Try this:

`layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.img_wstat_tstorm));`

Comment: setBackground expects *Drawable* Id only

Comment: You are incorrect.
From the API docs: 

android.view.View.setBackground(Drawable background);

Parameters: background  The Drawable to use as the background, or null to remove the background.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
myView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.id.my_drawable)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//Java
view.setBackground(ActivityCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg))

//Kotlin 
view.background = ActivityCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is correct in my case 
Solve this problem

```
 imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[productItem.getPosition()]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using a minSdkVersion 16 and targetSdkVersion 23
The following is working for me, it uses 
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.drawable);

Instead of using:    `layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_wstat_tstorm));`

Rather use:

`layout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.img_wstat_tstorm));`

`getActivity()` is used in a fragment, if calling from a activity use `this`

Comment: Question is asked for minSdk 15

Answer (score -1):

```
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.Nome_imgem));
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Comment: It really would help if you would wrap up in a few words what you are trying to do here...