# How to make circular button in android

Tags: android

I have an app in which i have to make circular button which i successfully made but what i want when i click button then change background drawable but when i do that circular button gets invisible. How do i do that

code:-

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:width="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <size android:width="150dp" android:height="150dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Batter to use `FloatingActionButton` why we put extra  afters

Comment: But how to change text and background according to data in floating button

Answer (score 5):

Use it -  `drawable/style_circular_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorDeepOrange"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOrange"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOrange"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And set that `style_circular_button.xml` on background of `Button` -

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btnSignin"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/text_btn_login"
   android:background="@drawable/style_circular_button"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

To change image by using code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v == ButtonName) {
     ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ImageName);
   }
}
```

Or, using an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_selected" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_mouse_over" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/login" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

In OnClick, just add this code:

```
ButtonName.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ImageName));
```

And you can use this drawable to obtain [desired circle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724737/4762767)

**UPD**: `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141279/setbackgrounddrawable-deprecated).