# setbackgrounddrawable dont works in android API 23

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

This code works in API > 23 but in API 23 don't work.
I need setBackground of the ImageButton one drawable image.

How do I solve this?

```
    ImageButton imgbt = findViewById(R.id.imgbt );

    imgbt .setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(EstadoDescritivo.this.getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                    R.drawable.ic_car)));
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141279/setbackgrounddrawable-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

Instead of using `setBackgroundDrawable`

```
imgbt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_car);
```

Hope this will help!