# XML Circle with gradient fill Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am trying to make an XML Button, circle shape, which is filled with a gradient color. This color needs to be changed programatically.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

My attempts to build this have ended up with a gradient background and a solid colored circle. Instead of the gradient circle and transparent background.

I am hoping to be able to use more then 2 colors or a radial gradient for the circle as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> You can Try with making Drawable XML. Example

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="circle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#555994"
        android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />    

</shape>
```

Arrange angle based on your requirement.

If you wants to change Color progarmatically then read this:-

[How do I programmatically set the background color gradient on a Custom Title Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115715/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-background-color-gradient-on-a-custom-title-ba)

Comment: Is there a shape called circle ?

Answer (score 1):

Belated but can be helpful for someone else

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient android:angle="0" android:endColor="#fff" android:gradientRadius="@dimen/_30sdp" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:type="radial" />
        <size android:width="@dimen/_25sdp" android:height="@dimen/_25sdp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Late but someone might get helped. Thanks to @Faizan

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#D10719" android:gradientRadius="120dp" android:startColor="#0A5A1B" android:type="linear" />
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Output:

[image]