# Flutter SDK No Smooth Gradient?

Tags: android, dart, gradient, flutter

The code below makes a radial gradient. However the gradient has no smooth transitioning from one color to the other. It has blocked transition like this

http://www.color-hex.com/palettes/7133.png

**Is there a way to make the gradient smooth?**

```
Color gradient_start = const Color (0xDD222222);
Color gradient_end = const Color (0xDD444444);

//some code

    new Container(
       decoration: new BoxDecoration(
         gradient:

         new  RadialGradient(
             colors: [gradient_start, gradient_end],
            radius: 1.0,
           stops: [
             0.0,
             0.5,
           ],

           tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
         )
       ),
```

Comment: use GradientDrawable like this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115715/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-background-color-gradient-on-a-custom-title-ba

Comment: https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/01/android-button-gradient-color.html

Answer (score 0):

remove the "stops" property to have a smooth transition!