# How to get colors from gradientDrawable on android Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, gradient, android-drawable, gradientdrawable

My app uses `GradientDrawable`. I have to get colors from `GradientDrawable` and set it as a background.

```
private int[] getGradientColors(GradientDrawable drawable) {
    // So I have to add this check, cause getColors() method requires min API 24 or higher
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
       return drawable;
    return Objects.requireNonNull(drawable).getColors();
}
```

Is there any alternative way to get this colors in API 23?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to set gradient as your layout background.

Adding this line to parent layout will set background as gradient

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

OR

Through code

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient);
```

Comment: You're right, but the gradient start color I'm getting from server.

Comment: Sorry i am new to android and don't know much.I search and I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116273/13485181

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. You'll have a great future))